# Horizontal Rule and Signature

Tags: rules, letters

I am here again with a new problem that I really need to get fixed. I like this template of cover letter but want to customize it as follows:

1. Want to have a thick horizontal rule(line) just below the email address (and above the date). I want the width of the line to be the same as the text width (instead of spanning the whole page).
2. Need to include a signature image below "Sincerely" and above my name.
3. If needed then want to include a "Logo" on top left side, that is, the address on right and logo on left. Highly appreciate any solution.

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{letter} 
\topmargin = -1.5in    % Make letterhead start about 1 inch from top of page 
%\textheight = 9.8in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
\textheight = 10.0in  % text height can be bigger for a longer letter
%\oddsidemargin = 0pt % leftmargin is 1 inch
\oddsidemargin = -0.5in % leftmargin is 1 inch
%\textwidth = 6.8in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin
\textwidth = 7.3in   % textwidth of 6.5in leaves 1 inch for right margin
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\signature{Khurshid Alam}
%\let\raggedleft\raggedright                % needed to get date flush left
\address{Khurshid Alam, Ph.D. \\
Department of Mathematics \& Statistics \\
University of Windsor \\
Windsor, ON, N9B 3P4 Canada \\
Phone: 1.226.961.1441 (Cell) \\
Email: azadka11@gmail.com} 
\vfill % forces letterhead to top of page
%\medskip\hrule height 1pt
\longindentation = 0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}
{Chair, Department of Statistics  \\
University of  \\
Canada \\ 
\vspace{.2in}
Subject: Application for a ... Position} 

\opening{Dear Sir,}
I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 


\closing{Sincerely}

\encl{(i) My CV, (ii) Teaching Philosophy Statement, and (iii) Teaching Evaluation Summary}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your original setup:

[image]

Here is a revised version that doesn't use the `letter` class, but `article` instead. It provides far more freedom to position and manipulate things:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[paper = a4paper,margin = 15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref,graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% A thick rule, 4 times the width of a regular rule
\newcommand{\thickhline}{\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height 4\arrayrulewidth \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}%
\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \includegraphics[height=7\baselineskip]{example-image}% Your logo
}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
  Khurshid Alam, Ph.D. \\
  Department of Mathematics \& Statistics \\
  University of Windsor \\
  Windsor, ON, N9B 3P4 Canada \\
  Phone: 1.226.961.1441 (Cell) \\
  Email: azadka11@gmail.com \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \thickhline \\[-.5\normalbaselineskip]
  \today
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
  Chair, Department of Statistics  \\
  University of \\
  Canada
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Subject: Application for a \ldots Position

\vspace{1.5\baselineskip}

Dear Sir,

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 

I am responding to the advertisement for the Assistant Professor position in the Mathematics \& Statistics Department at , which appeared on academickeys.com. 


Sincerely

\bigskip

\includegraphics[height=4\baselineskip,width=.3\linewidth]{example-image}% Your signature

Khurshid Alam

\bigskip

encl: (i) My CV, (ii) Teaching Philosophy Statement, and (iii) Teaching Evaluation Summary

\end{document}
```

It should be clear from the context what goes where and how to change it.